# How to correct inject map of bean in spring context

Tags: java, spring

I am using component-scan in my spring application. So in spring context I created map:

```
<util:map id="mapByName" map-class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap">
    <entry key="Name1" value-ref="MyCustomClassName1" />
</util:map>
```

and in my class annotated by @Service I want to inject this property:

```
@Inject
private Map<String, MyCustomClassName1> mapByName;
```

this is still working. Problem just in name of key. When I print this property I got `[MyCustomClassName1=org.my.package.service.MyCustomClassName1@cb52f2]`

so as you can see name of key is changed from Name1->MyCustomClassName1 (Name of this class). So my question is how to define custom key name in map property ?

Comment: Do you have the ability to use Java Config in your project?

Comment: For me, I use xml for this type of injection. If it can be done using @Inject, please let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quote from [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire):

> An autowired Maps values will consist of all bean instances that match the expected type, and the Maps keys will contain the corresponding bean names.

I think that just changing `@Inject` with `@Resource` will do it.

Answer (score 17):

If I were you, I would use Java Config to create a Map, since Java is the best way to create a Java object :) :).
Your configuration code would look like this:

```
@Bean(name = "mapBean")
public Map<String, MyCustomClassName1> mapBean() {
    Map<String, MyCustomClassName1> map = new HashMap<>();
    //populate the map here - you will need to @Autowire the references if they are not defined in this configuration
    return map;
}
```

And then I would inject it into wherever it's needed like so:

```
@Resource(name="mapBean")
private Map<String, MyCustomClassName1> map;
```

Note the use of `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired` or `@Inject`

Comment: what will be a key in the map, and is it possible to redefine it (say, using enum)?

Comment: Wondering why have to use `@Resource` rather than `@Autowired` as per usual? Even as of Spring 5.1 `@Autowired` still wasn't injecting the Map, suddenly started working when I switched to using `@Resource`. Possibly because of key being String type?