# Do I need to synchronize @Autowired method in Spring when I want to save multiple beans in collection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Let's imagine I have the next classes in the project based on Spring framework:

```
interface I {
    String getName()
}

@Component
class I1 implements I {
    @Override
    String getName() {return "I1"}
}

@Component
class I2 implements I {
    @Override
    String getName() {return "I1"}
}
```

And I want to gather them all in the map using the `@Autowired` method:

```
@Component
public class A {
    private Map<I> map = new HashMap<>()

    @Autowired
    public registerI(I i) {
        map.put(i.getName(), i)
    }
}
```

Should I make this method `registerI` synchronized? I mean, can Spring call this method in several threads simultaneously? Or this method will be called sequentially?

Thanks

Comment: you can just try it and find out. And why would it be called multiple times?

Comment: `Map` should be `List` right ?

Comment: @Deadpool it doesn't matter in this case. I want to know - do I need to use synchronized collection here or not.

Comment: @f1sh I didn't reproduce any race condition error in that case, but I am not still sure that it is correct code.

Comment: is the method even called twice?

Comment: @f1sh yes, it's called twice in that example.

Comment: Why not use a List<I> as the parameter in the method? That will ensure only one method call.

Comment: Or even better: use constructor injection and pass the List<I> as argument to the constructor.

Comment: Or even better just inject `Map<String, I>` and Spring will automatically inject all the beans into the map itself, just like it does for a collection. Although it will use the bean name and not the `getName` method.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `synchronized` because Spring bean initialization [is single-threaded and thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18510395/1602555). You can think of gotchas like thread-scoped or lazy beans but for regular singleton beans initialization happens in one thread.

You might want to use `synchronized` to make sure that after `registerI()` method is called your object is [safely published](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication), although auto-wired constructor with `final` field is more readable.

```
@Component
public class A {
    private final Map<String, I> map;

    public A(List<I> list) {
        map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(I::getName, i -> i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response. Can you provide a link on documentation, where is said, that spring bean initialization is single-threaded?

Comment: There is [Parallel bean initialization during startup \[SPR-8767\] #13410](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13410) which suggested to implement the multi-threaded singleton initialization. It was discussed but never implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You will get an exception during app startup because Spring cannot determine the correct implementation of interface "I" what you want to inject. You should use @Qualifier.

If you want to accomplish that scenario, this should be enough.

```
@Component
    public static class A {
        private Map<String,I> map = new HashMap<>();

        public A(List<I> list) {
            //map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(I::getName, x -> x));
            for (I i : list) {
                map.put(i.getName(), i);
            }
        }
    }
```

You will end with only one value in the map.

The commented line works if there are not duplicate map keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire context and get all the interested beans from it in a `@PostConstruct` method and create a hashmap with it.

Or

If you want that Map to be shared amongst multiple classes, make it a `@Bean`

```
@Configuration
class SomeConfig{

  @Autowire Context context;
  @Bean(name = "mapBean")
  public Map<String, MyCustomClassName1> mapBean() {
    Map<String, MyCustomClassName1> map = new HashMap<>();
    //populate the map here - from Context
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630255/how-to-correct-inject-map-of-bean-in-spring-context

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134333/how-to-create-a-simple-factory-pattern-with-autowired-beans-in-spring

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446301/autowire-reference-beans-into-list-by-type

Answer (score 0):

Spring fills List by your beans. After you can create map in postConstruct

```
@Component
public class A {

  @Autowired
  private List<I> list;

  @Autowired
  private Map<String, I> map;   

  @PostConstruct
  private void init(){
    map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(I::getName, element->element);
  }
}
```