# SpringBoot: @Configuration @bean method re-evaluate on every invocation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following classes:

```
@Configuration 
public class ConfigurationProvider {

   @Bean
   Map<Long, Long> provideTierConfigurations(TierDAL dal) {
        return dal.getTierConfigurations();
   }

   ...
}

@Component
public class TierCalculator {

   private Map<Long,Long> tierConfigurations;

   @Autowired
   public void setTierConfigurations(Map<Long, Long> tierConfigurations) {
      this.tierConfigurations = tierConfigurations;
   }

   ....
}
```

The key point is that the internal map in `TierDAL#getTierConfigurations` gets updated from time to time and `TierCalculator` should always hold the latest copy.

It feels like I need `ConfigurationProvider#provideTierConfigurations` to be re-evaluated every time and not only upon creation.

What's the proper way to handle this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you want to use up-to-date `Map<Long,Long>` somewhere inside `TierCalculator` right? If yes then don't create a `@Bean` with this `Map<Long,Long>` inside `@ConfigurationProvider`. You can just inject your `TierDAL` into `TierCalculator` and then somewhere in your `TierCalculator` you can use `dal.getTierConfigurations()` which will load your up-to-date `Map<Long, Long>`

here is an example code how to do that

```
@Component
public class TierCalculator {

   private final TierDAL dal;

   public TierCalculator(TierDAL dal){
       this.dal = dal
   }


   public void yourBusinessLogicMethod() {
      dal.getTierConfigurations(); // and do whatever you want :)
   }

   ....
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that will work - but in some cases it might create a Dependency cycle which I would like to prevent.

Comment: So you should definitely redesign your program that this dependency cycle is not present. You can follow [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) to achieve that. For start you can simply create an interface out of TierDAL, create a Bean with this interface and inject the interface inside the TierCalculator, then you will not have any direct dependency on TierDAL class

Answer (score 0):

To inject the last instance of a map as a bean, you need to use the annotation `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`

Please check this:
[How to correct inject map of bean in spring context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630255/how-to-correct-inject-map-of-bean-in-spring-context)

Comment: The @Resource should be annotated on a setter or can be on the constructor?

Comment: Not working fo me...I've tried to use @Resource on setter/constructor or simple class member ...but it doesn't do the trick. It does re-evaluate `ConfigurationProvider#provideTierConfigurations`.